# user details save in asp.net identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have the following `POST` method to save edit user details:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit_User(EditUserViewModel editUser, HttpPostedFileBase upload)
{
    var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new DBEntities());

    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(editUser.Id);

            if (user == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            user.UserName = editUser.UserName;
            user.Email = editUser.Email;
            ...

            // update the user information

            await UserManager.UpdateAsync(user);
            var ctx = store.Context;
            ctx.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Method", "Controller");
        }
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return View(editUser);
    }

    return View(editUser);
}
```

But here I'm not getting any error once its going to save data in AspNetUser table, it's jumping to catch exception.

How to save this edit user details properly?

Comment: What's the exception details?

Comment: though its jumping to exception , its again load the previous view without modified data

Comment: If it's jumping to the exception, you should be able to get the exception details from the `ex` object, including the exception type and possible reasons.

Comment: Is this ASP.NET Core (ASP.NET 5)?

Comment: @Kez as Steve pointed out - you need to tell us what the exception is that is being caught. Try adding the following to the `catch` statement and update your post to include the information from the Output Debug window: `Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Caught Exception {0} \r\n{1}\r\n{2}", ex.GetType(), ex.Message, ex.StackTrace));`

Comment: @Steve I have Identity column field , once I'm going to update , that field also trying update , but it can't  , so  how can I restrict not to update identity column field in asp.net ?

Comment: @kez I don't know what you mean, but without seeing your exception I'm going to guess that you have a detached entity, since you are getting and saving your `user` object to two different context instances.

Comment: Once I put debug point at exception , that the exceptions I found , `Message = "Cannot update identity column 'FileId'."` FieldId is the identity column here

Answer (score 0):

Did you change your key using the following method:
http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity

which contains the following steps. You need to ensure you get each one correcct.

```
Change the type of the key in the Identity user class
Add customized Identity classes that use the key type
Change the context class and user manager to use the key type
Change start-up configuration to use the key type
For MVC with Update 2, change the AccountController to pass the key type
For MVC with Update 3, change the AccountController and ManageController to pass the key type
```